# Do similar characteristic functions imply quantitative similarity in CDF?

Tags: probability, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

Suppose two $d$-dimensional r.v. $\xi,\eta$ have similar characteristic functions $\varphi_\xi(t)$ and $\varphi_\eta(t)$, like $$\sup_{t\in \mathbb R^d} |\varphi_\xi(t) - \varphi_\eta(t)| \leq \varepsilon$$
Can we bound the difference of cdf of the two r.v. when $x=0$  in terms of $\varepsilon$, i.e.
$$
|F_\xi(0) - F_\eta(0)|\leq k\varepsilon
$$
for some $k$ only depends on $d$?

If it helps, you can assume $\xi,\eta$ have compact support, and you can relax $k\varepsilon$ to any function of $\varepsilon$ that will tends to $0$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$, so long as it's independent to $\xi,\eta$.

Thanks!

Comment: The [Plancherel Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) might help you.

Comment: @Vincent.W. sorry, could you give more details about this? I fail to understand how Plancherel Theorem helps this. Thanks!